# How deploy java derby application for distribution to other clients

Tags: java, database, swing, user-interface, derby

I have developed an application which works with derby database, all things are ok on my machine, i started the database server from the netbeans.

Is there any method to copy the database structure and data for distribution to my clients?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to copy the contents of the database folder as is.

The database directory consists usually of one file `service.properties` and two directories: `log` and `seg0`.

If your application is the only one accessing this database on the client, then you should consider to use embedded mode, to avoid the installation of the Derby network server.